# SignalR better way to update knockout models from hub client methods

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, knockout.js, signalr, typescript

Considering something like this:

```
var postHub = $.connection.postHub;
function Post(post)
{
    function pk()
    {
        return self.PostId;
    }
    self = this;
    self.PostId = 0;
    self.Text = ko.observable('');
    self.Comments = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Votes = ko.observable(0);
    self.CommentToEdit = new Comment();
    self.NewComment = new Comment();
    if(post)
    {
       self.PostId = post.PostId || 0;
       self.Text = ko.observable(post.text) || ko.observable('');
       //etc..
    }
}
var vm = function()
{
     self = this;
     self.Posts = ko.obervableArray(mappedPosts);
     self.StandalonePost = new Post(mappedStandalonePost);
     self.PostToEdit = new Post();
     self.NewPost = new Post();
}
```

Hub server methods for PostHub

```
get(pk);
add(item);
delete(item);
update(item);
```

Hub client methods for PostHub

```
add(item);
delete(item);
update(item);
updateVotes(pk, votes);
```

How would I delgate client methods to standalone model and collection of models?

for example:

In vm I would implement something like this, and that's fine

```
postHub.client.updateVotes = function(pk, count)
{
      var post = getbyId(self.Posts(), pk) //getById uses ko.arrayFirst on pk() of model
      post.Votes(count);
}
```

But then I need different implementation for standalone model.
To have only one implementation pre vm, 
I could do something like this, but it seems so ugly:

```
postHub.client.updateVotes = function(pk, count)
{
      var post = getbyId(self.Posts(), pk) //getById uses ko.arrayFirst on pk() of model

      //check every standalone model

      if(!post && self.StandalonePost().pk() == pk )
      {
         post = self.StandalonePost(); 
      }

      post.Votes(count);
}
```

How would I implement one place where I could update all models that are in use? Is there some pattern I could implement (subscribe & publish comes to mind, can be in typescript too)?

Answer (score 1):

I have a library called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy. It's designed with MVVM in mind. It wraps SignalR both on server and client. Once set up you can do this from any model

```
ViewModel = function() {
    signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.Events.MyEvent, this.onMyEvent, this);
};

ViewModel.protoype = {
   onMyEvent: function(e) {
      //Act on MyEvent
   }
};
```

Check the wiki for how to set it up

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

Comment: Looks very nice! I understand how it should work, but I can't figure out how would avoid "the ugly part", Can you expand your answer and show me an example how would I and implement it in my case?

Comment: You shouldn't do it in one place (Your question is a bit vague). Thats the fine part with Event aggregation. Anyone that want to listen and act on a certain type of event can do it totally decoupled from all the other listeners. If you want to reuse code then you should instead have base classes for your viewmodels or similar